# Simulate cataract vision in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on a project to design a low vision aid. What is the image processing operation which can simulate cataract vision to the normal eye using OpenCV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be useful if you described the symptoms of the cataract and what happens to the retinal images since not all the people here are experts in computer vision and eye deceases at the same time. If a retinal image gets out of focus and gets a yellow tint you can used openCV [blur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.blur) function and also boost RGB values with yellow a bit. If there are different degree of blur across a visual field I recommend using integral images, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22447727/457687)

[image]
I guess there are at least three operations to do: add noise, blur, whiten:

```
Rect rect2(0, 0, w/2, h);
Mat src = I4(rect2).clone();
Mat Mnoise(h, w/2, CV_8UC3);
randn(Mnoise, 100, 50);
src = src*0.5+Mnoise*0.5; // add noise
Mat Mblur;
blur(src, Mblur, Size(12, 12)); // blur
Rect rect3(w, 0, w/2, h);
Mat Mblurw = Mblur*0.8+ Scalar(255, 255, 255)*0.2; //whiten
```

Comment: Sry about that Vlad. Those with cataracts commonly experience difficulty in appreciating colors and changes in contrast, driving, reading, recognizing faces, and coping with glare from bright lights. An example image is here http://www.medimanage.com/Images/cataractvision.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad :). It works perfect with other test Images too.

Comment: That link in the comment is not dead, but ... rogue? I'm sure it worked 9 years ago, so not complaining. I landed here because I was googling for simulations of cataracts. That image in the answer is the best I've found to illustrate what I've been experiencing lately. At the moment I'm somewhere between the left and the center image when out in the sunlight, except I see sharp. It's just "fog" that makes seeing somewhat difficult. As a software developer, I'm lucky in that almost all my tools and the OS has dark themes. Fortunately I live in an age when this problem is easily fixed.